# OSX menu bar application not launching when archived and exported, how to debug?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, build

After a big overhaul an OSX application I am building stopped launching after archive->export. It doesn't produce any errors, but doesn't launch at all either. I have tried various signing combinations, and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

The application launches fine when run from xcode.

The application is done in swift and uses cocoapods. It is a menu bar application.

My question is: How do you debug an application that works fine when debugging but not launches at all when archived->exported?

Xcode 7.3
OSX 10.11.5

**UPDATE:**

When I run the released application from command line it outputs:

```
Discipline.app/Contents/MacOS/Discipline 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Pods_Discipline.framework/Versions/A/Pods_Discipline
  Referenced from: /Users/theisegeberg/Desktop/Discipline 2016-05-24 09-21-14-uns/Discipline.app/Contents/MacOS/Discipline
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: You are exporting an archive and then running the application where?  On a computer running OS X 10.9?

Comment: Xcode 7.3, OSX 10.11.5

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay with a combination of cocoapods 1.0.0 and the Realm pod and xcode 7.3. The solution was to update xcode to 7.3.1 and use the downloaded version of the Realm lib.